# .NET Core NETSTANDARD - Get Assemblies

Tags: .net-core, appdomain, .net-standard-1.5

Because `AppDomain` ist not available in the `netstandard` library,
i am wondering how to do

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

The goal is obviously to get all assemblies that are loaded in the current app.

### Update

There is a solution for `netstandard 1.6`

```
DependencyContext.Default.CompileLibraries
DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries
```

but i need a solution from `netstandard >= 1.3`

Comment: May I ask why netstandard >= 1.3 ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/libraries

Comment: Yes I know that doc, but still I dont understand why someone would stay at 1.3... Windows Phone is 1.2 and Universal Windows Apps support 1.4... So, unless you are stuck with .NET Framework 4.6 and unable to upgrade to 4.6.2, I really don't understand why 1.3. Or did I missunderstood the article?

Comment: @dknaack Why my DependencyContext has no Default property :(